# Turning dynamic div content into a link

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on Longtail's JW Player and I am stuck with some basic stuff. I don't know what it is called in the programming language thats why I will write it step by step:

There is a javascript code to show title and description of the playing video, as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var player    =  null;
  var playlist  =  null;

  function playerReady(obj)
  {
    player = gid(obj.id);
    displayFirstItem();
  };

  function displayFirstItem()
  {
    try
    {
      playlist = player.getPlaylist();
    }
    catch(e)
    { 
      setTimeout("displayFirstItem()", 100);
    }

      player.addControllerListener('ITEM', 'itemMonitor');
      itemMonitor({index:player.getConfig()['item']});
  };
  function itemMonitor(obj)
  {
    gid('nowplaying').innerHTML = 'Playing: ' + playlist[obj.index]['title'] + ''; 
    gid('author').innerHTML = '<p>Author: ' + playlist[obj.index]['author'] + '</p>'; 
    gid('description').innerHTML = '<p>Description: ' + playlist[obj.index]['description'] + '</p>'; 
  };
  function gid(name)
  {
    return document.getElementById(name);
  };
</script>
```

Code returns the video title in to a div:

```
<div id="nowplaying"></div>
```

What I want is to display video title also in the tweet this button:

```
href="http://twitter.com/home?status=SONG TITLE"
```

How can I do this? Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `itemMonitor()` function:

```
  function itemMonitor(obj)
  {
    gid('nowplaying').innerHTML = 'Playing: ' + playlist[obj.index]['title'] + ''; 
    gid('author').innerHTML = '<p>Author: ' + playlist[obj.index]['author'] + '</p>'; 
    gid('description').innerHTML = '<p>Description: ' + playlist[obj.index]['description'] + '</p>';
    gid('tweetLink').href = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(playlist[obj.index]['title']);
  };
```

This requires that a link be present in the document with `id="tweetLink"`, this doesn't alter the link's text, however, if you want to update the link's text:

```
  function itemMonitor(obj)
  {
    gid('nowplaying').innerHTML = 'Playing: ' + playlist[obj.index]['title'] + ''; 
    gid('author').innerHTML = '<p>Author: ' + playlist[obj.index]['author'] + '</p>'; 
    gid('description').innerHTML = '<p>Description: ' + playlist[obj.index]['description'] + '</p>';
    gid('tweetLink').href = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(playlist[obj.index]['title']);
    gid('tweetLink').innerHTML = 'Tweet this song: ' + playlist[obj.index]['title'] + '.';
  };
```